# Azure authenticator account icon - company logo?

Tags: azure, azure-authentication, authenticator

does anyone know if it's possible to add a custom image to account in Azure Authenticator App?
For all of our accounts, it always shows either user's photo uploaded to AAD, or generic badge image

We want to add an image of our company to an account, rather than individual images of users, or generic badge. We still want to keep photos of users in AAD. 
I believe there should be a way to achieve this, because if I add GitHub account, it automatically creates account with GitHub logo:
[image: Azure Authenticator with GitHub logo and generic badge image for our account]

Thanks,
Jiri

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Do add your feedback on it here - https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory. Also ask your query in Azure Authenticator App TechNet forum to get assistance on this query - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=MicrosoftAuthenticatorApp

Comment: I've checked GitHub otpauth URI and all they have there is a secret and issuer=GitHub, no icon path or anything. This means it's just the Authenticator App is smart enough to store some big companies' logos and identifies them by an issuer name. It does the same for Twitter. So, looks like no way to provide a custom logo, unfortunately. At least so far.

Comment: looking for the same thing, does that work for anyone else?

Comment: I started to see logos (also for Azure tenants) maybe MS changed something.

Answer (score 1):

I just check on the APK files.
I didn't see other picture than:

```
ic_amazon_account.xml
ic_dropbox_account.xml
ic_facebook_account.xml
ic_github_account.xml
ic_google_account.xml
ic_lastpass_account.xml
ic_linkedin_account.xml
ic_samsung_account.xml
ic_slack_account.xml
ic_twitter_account.xml
```

You can generate with:

```
qrencode -t utf8 'otpauth://totp/test?secret=4444444&digits=6&issuer=lastpass'
```

Comment: looking for the same thing, does that work for anyone else?